# Problem when reading from JSON file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {


        $("#Button1").click(function() {

           $.getJSON("ticketPriceInArray.js", 
        function(json) {
       var ticketPriceArray=[json.tickets[0].price, json.tickets[1].price,               
                json.tickets[2].price, json.tickets[3].price, json.tickets[4].price, 
                json.tickets[5].price];

                         alert(json.tickets[0].type);

         var inputWord =$("#keyword").val();
             if (inputWord=="A"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[0]);}   
             if (inputWord=="B"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[1]);}
             if (inputWord=="C"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[2]);}   
             if (inputWord=="D"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[3]);}   
             if (inputWord=="E"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[4]);}   
             if (inputWord=="F"){$("#result").text(ticketPriceArray[5]);}       
         });

       });
  });    
  </script>
```

Here is "ticketPriceInArray.js"

```
{ 
"tickets":[
      {
    "type":"A Ticket",
    "price":220,
  },

  {
    "type":"B Ticket",
    "price":180,
  },

  {
    "type":"C Ticket",
    "price":120,
  },

  {
    "type":"D Ticket",
    "price":100,
  },

  {
    "type":"E Ticket",
    "price":80,
  },

  {
    "type":"F Ticket",
    "price":50,
  }
  ]
}
```

This is a simple html where when the corresponding text inputed, the corresponding ticket price will show in the html after a button-click.  All the ticket info is stored in a .json file named "ticketPriceInArray.js" and I have been trying to read it using $.getJSON(), but unfortunately I haven't been able to get any success.  The weird thing is I didn't get any warning on anything so I couldn't fix it.  Please see if you can give me any suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: Using Firebug or the Chrome developer tools, can you check the network traffic to see if the JSON data is actually being fetched from the server, and that it contains the expected content. If so, try alerting the `json` variable as soon as the callback is called, to make sure that a) it is called, and b) it contains the correctly-parsed JSON data.

Comment: And using the latest JQuery version, current release is v1.6.1 : http://jquery.com/

Comment: After checking the network traffic, I didn't see any JSON file there.  Maybe the JSON file isn't fetched at all.  I have already put the JSON file in the same folder as the html.  Is there anything that I didn't do properly?

Answer (score 2):

By adding an AJAX error handler, I received this

```
"parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

The problem is the trailing commas after each price property.

Comment: I have removed all the trailing commas from the JSON files but it is not working.  I couldn't get the alert window popping.

Comment: @iSpeakBinary I have setup a quick [demo](http://staging.philipbrown.id.au/test.html) that is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different approach to solving this problem. This is assuming that you aren't changing your ticket prices based on some data that you pass to the url.

ticketPriceInArray.js

```
{ 
    "A" : 220,
    "B" : 180,
    "C" : 120,
    "D" : 100,
    "E" : 80,
    "F" : 50
  };
```

main file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var ticket_prices = {};

  $(function() {
     $("#Button1").click(function() {

        $.getJSON("ticketPriceInArray.js", function(returnedJSON) {
            ticket_prices = returnedJSON;
            $("#result").text( ticket_prices[ $("#keyword").val() ] );
        });

     });
  });    
</script>
```

If there are any considerations (or questions about my assumptions) let me know and I will update based on that.

Comment: Yeah I got what you saying.  But my goal is to read data from a JSON file and display it on the web upon the search button being clicked.  I am a little frustrated coz I am stuck here at this problem for much longer than I thought.  Hopefully, this can be solved soon.  Thanks for your suggestion tho, natedavisolds.  What should I do if I want to achieve the above mentioned goal?

Comment: No problem.  If it's the answer for you, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following example is working fine in FF and Chrome with the exact JSON you provided. In IE you will have to remove the commas after the prices, as Phil already said.

In my test both the test.html and test.js were placed in my apache server root; viewing the files directly from my desktop into my browser didn't work apparently due to security restrictions.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#Button1").click(function() {
                $.getJSON("test.js", function(json) {
                    for (var i in json.tickets) {
                        var type = json.tickets[i].type;
                        var price = json.tickets[i].price;
                        $('#result').append('<span>type: ' + type+ ', price: ' + price + '</span><br />');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button id="Button1">click me</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSONs; or just rely on a good encoder instead of doing it by hand ;)

Comment: Thanks, agonzalez.  It is really helpful.  I don't know there is encoder that can produce JSON file.  Any links?  Thank you again, man.

Comment: Well, there are plenty. It depends on the language. For Java there is [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), PHP has its native [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and for javascript you could try using jquery or prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following facts:

- you're using firefox
- there is no traffic in the network-tab when you click on #Button1
- there are no errors logged

... I would like to say:
**the element you click on is not `$("#Button1")`**

Are you sure that the element you click on has the ID "Button1" and that there is **only one** element using that ID ?

Are you running this from a webserver or from your local filesystem?

Comment: Here is the body of my website.
<body>       
    <input id="keyword" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" />
    <hr />
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>

As you can see, "Button1" does exist.